# Proof that $e^{n}-\lfloor e^{n} \rfloor \neq \frac{1}{2} $ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, how can I proof that $e^{n}-\lfloor e^{n} \rfloor$ is never equal to $\frac{1}{2}$?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**: If we have

$$e^{n} = \frac{1}{2} + \lfloor e^n \rfloor \in \Bbb{Q}$$

then $e$ would be an algebraic number.

Comment: Not to mention that this would imply that $e$ is rational.

Comment: @Patrick No; it would only imply that a power of $e$ is rational. This is weaker (consider $\sqrt{2}$, for example).

Comment: I was just taking $n=1$ for your equation.

Comment: @Patrick But the question is asking to prove the equality holds for no $n$, not just $n = 1$.

Comment: That was a semantic issue on my part. I read it as: Prove it isn't true for all $n$ so finding one $n$ where it didn't hold would do it. Do you see what I mean? I do get that this wasn't the OPs question. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: IF $e^{n} = \frac{1}{2} + \lfloor e^n \rfloor$, then since $e^n > n + 1 $ we would have $ \lfloor e^n \rfloor > \frac{1}{2} + n $